# How to write an SQL command to input a column by using data from another column in the same table?

Tags: mysql, sql, xampp

Here, I would like to generate passwords for each employee and the passwords are the last 6 digits of the corrosponding employee_ID. What is the required SQL statement? Thanks

```
Employee_ID  | Password    
------------------------
E200102      | NULL
E199500      | NULL
E200410      | NULL
E199606      | NULL
E200303      | NULL
E199206      | NULL
E198703      | NULL
E198405      | NULL
```

The expected results are the following.

```
Employee_ID  | Password    
------------------------
E200102      | 200102
E199500      | 199500
E200410      | 200410
E199606      | 199606
E200303      | 200303
E199206      | 199206
E198703      | 198703
E198405      | 198405
```

Answer (score 1):

seems you just want remove the firts char 
for this You could update and  use substr()

```
 Update  your_table  
 set password =  substr(Employee_ID  , 2);
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
UPDATE Table_Name SET password = SUBSTR(Employee_ID, 2);
```

This will iterate through all rows in your_table_anme and replace password with itself minus the first character.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below,

```
Update Table_Name
Set Password = Substr(Employee_ID, 2)
```

this query basically removes the first char from the employee_id, and updates it as password.